# How do I memory profile a UWP app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am trying to optimize a windows UWP app for memory, and I don't know how to make sense of the information that the built-in profiling tools give me.

What I have attempted so far is:

1. Create a new project.  Select a **Blank App(Universal Windows)**
2. Change **Debug** to **Release**
3. Uncheck **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**
4. go to **Debug->Start Diagnostic Tools without debugging**
5. check **Memory Usage**
6. Click on the gear next to **Memory Usage** and make sure **Mixed (Managed and Native)** is selected.
7. Click **Start**
8. Click **Take snapshot**.
9. After the snapshot is taken, click **Stop**

Results

- The built-in Task manager says that App1 is using **17.1 MB** of memory
- when I hover my mouse over the memory usage bar in visual studio, IT tells me that it's using **36.1 MB** of memory.
- When I run the app without the debugger, task manager tells me that it's using 14.3MB of memory
- The snapshot tells me that there was **79.98 KB** on the Managed Heap(yes, KB), and **4.62MB** on the "Heap"

---

I don't know what to make of this.  If It it were only a marginal difference, it'd be okay with it, but almost 2/3 of the memory that Task Manager told me the app was using is unaccounted for in the snapshot.  My real application has a similar issue, except with more memory across the board.

How do I profile the rest of the memory?

Comment: Memory includes not just the heap, but also the memory used by code and static data, the stack, etc. Some of this memory can be shared with other processes, some cannot. Different tools give different views on the data.